# Does Vietnam have English speaking emergency telephone numbers?

Tags: vietnam

If an expat required the emergency services in Vietnam but does not speak Vietnamese, is there an emergency telephone number available with English speakers on the line ?

By emergency services, I am specifically interested in ambulance, police and fire & rescue services.

Answer (score 1):

No there are no dedicated numbers like 12345 in China for example. Most guides explained it is best to have hotel staff etc to help out with the call